# PowerShell - .count() not working on an array of strings

Tags: arrays, powershell, count

I'm probably over thinking this, but I have an array of strings and when I enter $[arrayname].count(); I get an error that it failed because system.string doesn't contain a method named 'count'.

I know this works with an array of integers, and I would think there would be an easier way to get how many values are in an array other than doing a forloop.

Below is a simplified example.  The example threw the error.

```
$Test=@("3","2","1")
$Test.count()
```

Comment: there is NO `.Count()` method on an array. [*grin*] there is a `.Count` _property, tho.

Comment: Thanks Lee_Dailey; that answered it for me.  Knew I was over-thinking it.

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to have helped a tad ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lee_Dailey actually answered this question.

I needed to use the property [.count] not the method [.count()]